# CVS commit into directory checked out as branch commits into trunk

Tags: version-control, branch, cvs

I created a new CVS branch, checked it out and addded some folder and files into it. Once I committed the branch changes the files and the directory were committed not into my branch as one would expect but into the trunk.

According to [this page](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/cvs-branches.html) this is caused ...

`Due to a bug in cvs 1.3 (on which rcvs is currently based), if you add a new file in a directory checked out on a branch, the file will appear on the main line, not on your branch. Caveat scriptor.`

So currently I have these new files in trunk only. Fortunatelly no harm. But how can I get those new files into the branch as well? Any tips? Ideally using IntelliJ 9.0 as CVS client. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it finally so sharing my experience:

- suprisingly adding new files to CVS branch is headache in general and everyone (except of myself) knew that.
- there are many clients which can't do that like IntelliJ 9 or SmartCVS 6 but there is at least one which is capable of this super-diffcult task of adding new files into a branch ...
- for me the winner was [tortoiseCVS](http://www.tortoisecvs.org/)

Comment: Hmm, adding new files to a branch isn't really difficult at all and even though I have never used either of the tools you cite I very much doubt they are incapable of doing this. As long as you update the working copy to the relevant branch **before** adding the files everything should be fine.

Comment: The slightly tricky thing in your case was that you had already added the files on the trunk and wanted to "copy" them to the branch after the fact (which also means they weren't "new" anymore, which in turn means that what you needed to do was not *adding* but **merging** and that is indeed a slightly more difficult topic - but still none that any self-respecting CVS frontend should have problems with).

Comment: I suggest you try the tools yourself then :) Because not only I saw it on my own eyes but moreover several people confirmed that CVS tools suffers from this bug. See the link in the question which describes the (well-know) bug which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case, this should do it (inside your working copy, from the parent folder of your new directory):

```
cvs up -rBranch
cvs up -jHEAD -d NewDirectory
```

I.e. update your working copy to the branch and then merge in changes from the trunk version of NewDirectory (creating it in the process (the `-d` argument)). You still need to commit after that.

Comment: I am currently working on some way older version in my branch than the trunk version so "merge any changes from trunk to this branch" will not work. But +1 for being the only one who replied :)

Comment: @Jan: actually the second command should not merge "*any* changes" but only the ones from NewDirectory... I'll reword that.

Comment: Didn't really got chance to try this but solved it using tortoiseSVN

Comment: @Jan: You mean TortoiseCVS, don't you?